# Prevent implementation of method that is not an interface method

Tags: c#, .net, interface

Is it possible to prevent implementation of public non interface methods in a class that implements an interface?

E.g.

```
    public interface ICanDoSomething
    {
        void CanDoA();

        void CanDoB();
    }

    public class Doer : ICanDoSomething
    {
        public void CanDoA()
        {
            //Do A
        }

        public void CanDoB()
        {
            //Do B
        }

        public void CanDoC()
        {
            //Don't do this!!! it's not defined in the interface!!!
        }
    }
```

Just to clarify, I would like to prevent it at compilation time, not at run time.

Comment: I'd be surprised if C# offers this kind of a feature, but you can easily write some pre-compile time script to enforce that. I'll stay around to read the answers :)

Comment: Do you have a use-case for this?

Comment: No specific use case, just want to direct those who use libraries to component oriented functionality and avoid god objects.

Comment: @shay__ can you post an example or reference to how I can implement and deploy such a script?

Comment: @Y.S You can write (1) pre-build script that executes a small tool (2), which use reflection to examine all classes that implement `ICanDoSomething` and ensure there are no additional methods. So in total, you need to write a small script and the tool itself (the tool can be in C#). Google "Pre-build Event" in visual studio.

Comment: Thanks Shay, plus 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If C# would be able to do what you want to achieve, the language itself would destroy one of object-oriented programming features: **encapsulation**.

Let implementers *implement* your interfaces their own way and focus on quality of interface implementations rather than putting your effort on *don't implement more methods than ones defined by the interface* (*i.e. implement an unit/integration test that implementers should pass to certify that black boxes actually work as you expect*).

When you use interfaces you get black boxes: you don't care about how an implementation does the job, but you care about *if it does the job right*.

Taken from some comment you added in your own question:

> No specific use case, just want to direct those who use libraries to
>   component oriented functionality and avoid god objects.

You want to avoid *god objects* but you want *god methods*. Everyone will always prefer a class which has a good separation of concerns and segmentation rather than see 3 methods with 1k code lines each one.

### OP said...

> What about breaking the single responsibility principle? If a class
>   implementing an interface suddenly starts doing stuff which can easily
>   be a responsibility of other class, isn't it breaking OOP as well?

No, single responsibility principle isn't tied to the definition of object-oriented programming (i.e. *inheritance, polymorphism and encapsulation*) but it's about **code quality**.

Code quality can't be ensured with interfaces nor using any own programming language construct. This is the mission of [*code review*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review).

Of course, automated testing ensures that code will run with quality, which is different than *coded with quality*.

Comment: Encapsulation is not destroyed. You can still create 100 interface. The only restriction is to disable the methods, that are not in the interfaces, that the class implements. Or am I mislead? We allow only 1 interface to implement?

Comment: @ntohl It actually destroys encapsulation because you can't decide how to implement the interface.

Comment: What about breaking the single responsibility principle? If a class implementing an interface suddenly starts doing stuff which can easily be a responsibility of other class, isn't it breaking OOP as well?

Comment: @Y.S I'm going to answer this as an update to the answer itself ;P

Comment: It's a good answer which suggests best practices and explanations so i'll accept it, it's not what I was looking for (which was a yes/now and how) but it provided me guidance to go in the right direction. :)

Comment: @Y.S Well, as others have pointed out, you could implement something with the new C# compiler platform, or use some like NRefactory to analyze the code externally. BTW, I believe that documenting some coding conventions requires less effort and it will work better in the long run...

Comment: @Y.S Imagine yourself adding new code validation rules whenever some developer does something wrong... It will sound like a joke, but if some dev refuses to follow team rules, maybe and sadly it's time to fire him/her. Don't waste your time trying to not educate your colleagues. Human conventions are better than automated conventions...

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can't prevent `CanDoC()` declaration, but you can do it *useless* via *factory method* and *internal implementation*:

```
// interface is public when its implementation is internal
internal class Doer : ICanDoSomething {
  // To prevent creating Doer as Doer
  protected internal Doer() { // or internal
    //Some staff if required
  }

  public void CanDoA() {... }

  public void CanDoB() {... }

  // Technically possible
  public void CanDoC() {... }
}

public static class DoerFactory {
  // ... create instead Doer as ICanDoSomething instance
  // (factory method)
  public static ICanDoSomething Create() {
    return new Doer();
  } 
}

...

ICanDoSomething test = DoerFactory.Create();

test.CanDoA(); // OK

test.CanDoC(); // Compile time error

(test as Doer).CanDoC(); // Compile time error when called in an assembly other than Doer
```

Comment: thanks, I actually thought of using a factory but was looking for a more elegant solution. Have you ever tried scripting the complitation process as suggested in Shay's comment above?

Comment: @Y.S. `Roslyn` https://roslyn.codeplex.com/ is probably what you're looking for since you have to parse the code and analyze it.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it.